# Android M: options menu background disappears

Tags: android

Faced a strange options menu behavior on Android M.

[image: Shadow disappears]

Menu shadow is implemented with 9 patch and works perfect on previous Android versions.
But on sixth Android it appears only for a while.
Also it look like it appears for a while during close animation.
Menu style is below:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shadow</item>
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>
```

Will be thankful for any help in fixing this shadows visibility issue.

Comment: Sixth Android is Android M. Android N is on 'preview early… really early' stage.

Comment: Thanks I edited the title, it's about Android M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove background from DropDown ListView style